# Error in Declaration of service within Grails service

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-services

I have concerns about the use of Services within other Services. Some work, but others don't. The problem is that I can't figure out what's wrong.

When you add a service that generates the error always occurs the same problem, then I withdraw the reference to service problematic and the system returns to normal.

I wonder if the same is effecting any circular reference creating instability.

```
class UserService {
    def terceirizadoService
    def unidadeService
    def grailsApplication
    def springSecurityService
    def tabService   //If I remove this line the system works
    ...
}


class TabService {
    def contratoService, grailsApplication ...
}
```

The error happens when the Bootstrap reference is made to a domain that has a reference to the tabService service.

```
class Car implements Serializable {
    transient tabService
    ...
}
```

and generates this log:

```
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘tabService’: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contratoService': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘userService’: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘tabService’: org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBeanNotInitializedException: FactoryBean is not fully initialized yet
->>  105 | methodMissing                    in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    558 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1
|    308 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    301 | executeForEnvironment            in     ''
|    277 | executeForCurrentEnvironment . . in     ''
|    262 | run                              in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                              in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contratoService': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘userService’: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘tabService’: org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBeanNotInitializedException: FactoryBean is not fully initialized yet
->>  105 | methodMissing                    in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
```

I'm using Grails 2.3.7

Comment: I've found in the past that circular references between services are OK as long as at least one of the services in the cycle is configured as non-transactional.  Is it possible for you to make any of your services `static transactional = false` and does this improve matters?

Comment: Thanks for replying Ian Roberts. The Complicated is that the services need to be transactional because many business rules are stored there. Do you know of another method that could solve this problem?

Comment: You'll run into problems as well if the services are `prototype` instead of `singleton`.

Answer (score 1):

We've seen issues like this whenever we use `prototype` scoped services as well (not sure if that applies to you).

As a work around you could solve it by not injecting the tabService but getting it on demand:

```
def getTabService() {
    grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean(TabService)
}
```

Not ideal, obviously.