# error deploy grails 1.3.7 app amazon

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, web-deployment

i develop a grails 1.3.7 and i now trying to deploy it on amazon cloud. i follow the steps explained on http://www.inoneo.com/en/blog/5/amazon-aws/deploy-a-grails-application-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk. amazon instance tomcat version is 7. I am able to connect using mysql native to amazon database. my production environment configuration is:

```
    production {
    dataSource {
        user = "{userDB}"
        password = "{passDB}"
        pooled = true
        dbCreate = "create"
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://{endPointRSD}:3306/{databaseName}?user={userDB}&password={passDB}"
        dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        properties {
            validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
            testOnBorrow = true
            testOnReturn = true
            testWhileIdle = true
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1800000
            numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1800000
        }
    }
}
```

However i get several errors. Seems to me i having troubles with transactional issues. But how can it happen when my app run just fine in development? Thanks

here goes the error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'claseDemandaService': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'claseDemandaService': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    ... 3 more
2014-09-13 13:51:42,393 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /principal/encabezado
```

Comment: Why do you need so old version of Grails? Now back to your question. Do your app runs normally at your develop machine?

Comment: yes. my app runs normally at my develop machine. Upgrade is something need to do. thanks

Comment: looking around i found a post that can be related at [links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685583/error-in-declaration-of-service-within-grails-service). The thing is that error output occurs once i try to deploy on tomcat v6, v7. any ideas?

Comment: And what Tomcat version on your machine? You must either install older tomcat on the server, either upgrade application.

Comment: i am using the tomacat 1.3.7 plugin for my grails version. Do you think my error can be due to  circular references between services, by comparison the error output form post [Error in Declaration of service within Grails service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685583/error-in-declaration-of-service-within-grails-service)?

Comment: hi everyone. I just fount out that the problems is actually due to circular references between services. thank for the concern. Now need to solve the problem.

Comment: I mean 'tomcat' as the app server not the plugin

Comment: Could you share your sources in some way?

Comment: the problem seems to me that is circular references between service. Would you please confirm?<blink>
class ClaseDemandaService {
    def usuarioService
}
class ProductoService {
    def claseDemandaService
}
class InvitacionService {
    def productoService
}
class EventoInvitacionService {
    def invitacionService
}
class EventoService {
    def productoService
    def invitacionService
    def usuarioService
}    </blink>

Comment: Is all of your services accessing to the database? If not then write in them 'static transactional = false'.

Comment: the thing is that all that services suppose to write in my DB. Is there form to solve this issue? thanks again for the concern.

Comment: I haven't ideas more for this time, but maybe they are appears if I'll look to your sources. Maybe removing circular reference will help.

Comment: sure. catalina output and the source files of services mentioned on the error log is at [Source Files](http://www.4shared.com/rar/scr_aQUuce/serviceSource.html) Remember i am using grail 1.3.7 deploying on a tomcat 6. That's when i get the error, deploying. thanks again

Comment: Ok, I've downloaded. Now I need about one day or two.

Comment: thanks again. if you need something else please just ask. i ll upload it immediately.

Comment: I'm sorry but i've got sick and didn't look at code still. I think I can do it at weekend.

Comment: I'm really sorry, still had no time to see it. But I'm not forgot about it.